# How to programatically generate a serialization assembly or cs file like XmlSerializer would when using XmlAttributeOverrides?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to generate a serialization assembly or .cs file to serialize my types using XmlAttributeOverrides, and then reference this assembly/.cs file in my project directly rather than use XmlSerializer to perform xml serialization/deserialization. This is because the serialization uses XmlAttributeOverrides and when you create an XmlSerializer with overrides it doesn't look for an existing assembly but will always re-generate one ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678676/precompile-xmlserializers-with-xmlattributeoverrides/1451168#1451168)). My program runs in an environment where it's not possible to run csc.exe, therefore my I cannot generate a serialization assembly at runtime.

To be clear, I can't just use sgen.exe because that only generates assemblies that perform the default xml serialization/deserialization. If you create an XmlSerializer and [pass it XmlAttributeOverrides in the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0.aspx) then Serialize() and Deserialize() do NOT use the assembly generated by sgen.exe, therefore sgen.exe seems of no use to me. When using overrides XmlSerializer will always generate a new assembly.

So, is there a way I can call XmlSerializer or other classes and get it to create a .cs file or dll that I can include in my project? I'd like to automate this process if possible so I don't need to make manual changes whenever I change my types that are being serialized. I can't use sgen.exe /k because that only generates the default XmlSerializer for a type instead of the one I need which uses overrides. Is there another way to generate or capture the .cs file that's created by XmlSerializer?

(I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333689/generating-an-xml-serialization-assembly-for-a-custom-xmlserializer) that's the root of this one)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the assemblies at compile time. In Visual Studio open project `properties`, click the `build` tab and scroll down to `Generate serialization assemblies`.

Setting this to `on` will compile them locally so that they may be deployed with your solution. They can also be compiled using the `Sgen.exe` tool. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx) for more info.

> **Generate serialization assembly**
>
> Specifies whether the compiler will use the XML Serializer Generator
>   Tool (Sgen.exe) to create XML serialization assemblies. Serialization
>   assemblies can improve the startup performance of XmlSerializer if you
>   have used that class to serialize types in your code. By default, this
>   option is set to Auto, which specifies that serialization assemblies
>   be generated only if you have used XmlSerializer to encode types in
>   your code to XML. Off specifies that serialization assemblies never be
>   generated, regardless of whether your code uses XmlSerializer. On
>   specifies that serialization assemblies always be generated.
>   Serialization assemblies are named TypeName.XmlSerializers.dll. For
>   more information, see [XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx).

From the last comment I see your issue. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678676/precompile-xmlserializers-with-xmlattributeoverrides), I believe if your using `XmlAttributeOverrides` the assembly will always be generated.

Hence if you can't launch csc.exe then don't use `XmlAttributeOverrides`.

Comment: No, those serialization assemblies are only for the default xml. If you use XmlOverrides when calling XmlSerializer.Serialize/Deserialize it can't use those serialization assemblies. Hence the problem.

Comment: Looking at reflector there is no way around this.